# Is there any way to store date and time data in an array in R?

Tags: arrays, r, datetime, dataframe

I understand that data.frame is of dimension 2 and array is like a matrix in higher dimensions so its elements should of the same data type. I wonder if there is any class or solution to store data including both date and time and numeric values to a variable of dimension 3. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your understanding of the restrictions on what matrices and arrays can hold is too limited. They can hold numeric, character, or lists, although any one of them, not multiple types. They just cannot have attribute lists, so they cannot be times or Dates. You probably should say exactly what it is that you want to acheive since most experienced R users would probably be reaching for a dataframe in long-form (aka "normal form").

Answer (score 0):

All elements in an array must be of the same data type. However; you can convert your date and time to "number of seconds since epoch" and use that since it is numeric. For example how to convert the current time:

```
>st <- Sys.Time()
>print(st)
[1] "2018-03-30 23:55:56 CDT"
>print(as.numeric(st))
[1] 1522472156
```

Answer (score 0):

A `"POSIXct"` vector such as `x` below can be given dimensions using `dim<-`

```
x <- Sys.time() + 1:8
dim(x) <- c(2, 2, 2)

class(x)
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

dim(x)
## [1] 2 2 2
```

It can alternately be written in this form:

```
x <- Sys.time() + 1:8
xx <- `dim<-`(x, c(2, 2, 2))
```